# Logging systemd service disable/enable

Tags: logging, systemd, debian-stretch

I'm looking for a way to get log messages for events like enabling or disabling services using systemctl.
Using

```
/bin/journalctl --utc -x -o json -f -t systemd -S now | jq .MESSAGE
```

starting & stopping is visible but even with `LogLevel=debug` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` enabling & disabling are not getting logged.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These actions aren't logged as they merely edit configuration in `/etc`, and systemctl often does so itself, bypassing systemd entirely (whether a unit is "enabled" is defined by having it symlinked under `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` or another similar directory).

To see which services were enabled and when, use global configuration tracking software such as *etckeeper*, or enable audit rules for /etc/systemd via `auditctl`.